# How to safely format URL

Tags: c#, string, sharepoint, concatenation

I have a SharePoint application that uses a URL to access a resource.

code:

```
return web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/UserSettings");
```

This works fine when I'm on a subsite, because `ServerRelativeUrl` will return `"/sitename"`

However, when this is a root site, `ServerRelativeUrl` will return `"/"` instead, leading to a poorly formed URL such as `"//lists/UserSettings"`

I know this seems like a simple problem (and it is) but is there a best practice for approaching this situation that is consistently safe?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the `System.Uri` and `System.UriBuilder` classes?

Comment: Either way I get an exception of : "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

Answer (score 1):

```
new Uri(web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/lists/UserSettings");
```

Okay, hrm...try:

```
Path.Combine(web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/lists/UserSettings");
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because web.ServerRelativeUrl is (not intuitively) a string. Trying to put the full string in gives me an exception of "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

Comment: What does the string version look like?

Comment: If the site is a root-site, it simply returns "/", which forms something like: "//lists/UserSettings", which is the invalid URI

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute url, this works for me:
web.GetList(web.Url + "/lists/UserSettings")

Answer (score 1):

```
return web.GetList( (web.ServerRelativeUrl == "/" ? string.Empty : web.ServerRelativeUrl) + "/lists/UserSettings");
```